# Replace several values in a column

Tags: pandas

I have a df with a column where I need to change several values, I know one of the methods would be:

```
  df = df.replace(['Blue', 'Yellow'], 'Green')
```

However I have way more items to replace, I did it in an not efficient way: replace1

```
  df = df.replace(['Blue', 'Yellow'], 'Green')
```

then replace2:

```
 df = df.replace(['Grey', 'Red'], 'Purple')
```

How can I add replace 2 to the replace1 condition so I can do it more efficiently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create a dict and use `.map` over ur column

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact replacement rule is, but the syntax is like this:

`df.replace({'Blue': 'Green', 'Grey': Purple})`

Comment: thanks, tried that too, but, lets say you need to put Yellow with Blue and Red with Grey, I tried {Blue,Yellow: Green} ... error, tried: [Blue,Yellow],Green    obviously error too :(

Comment: it is wrong I do not know how to add a list of values to replace and then in the same condition add another list for a different value

Comment: Why is there a list? Please edit your question to show what the DataFrame looks like.

Comment: Maybe you mean:
```df.replace({['Blue', 'Yellow']: 'Green', ['Grey', 'Red']: Purple})```

Comment: Hi, yes that's what I need however I get this error: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: So each entry in the DataFrame is a list? That's going to be tricky.